# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\tan(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{1}{n})^2} $

Tags: calculus

How can I show the following series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\tan(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{1}{n})^2} $$

Converge?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should show your work and effort.

Comment: I Understand, I have tried to use some of the theorems. The hint on the book was to find a upper bound for the sequence, But I couldn't find one.

Comment: You should edit your question adding the detail of your work and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - x\right) = \cot(x)$, and also that $\cot(x) = \frac{1}{\tan(x)}$. Hence, what you're actually trying to evaluate is:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \tan^2\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)
\end{align}
$$

Furthermore, it is [well known](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.0859.pdf) that $\tan(x/2) \leq \frac{2x}{\pi}$ for $ x\in [0,\pi/2]$. Indeed, taking $x_n := \frac{2}{n}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we find that for $n\geq 2$, $x_n\in[0,\pi/2]$. Hence, it follows that for $N\geq 2$:

$$
\begin{align}
0 \leq\sum_{n=1}^{N} \tan^2\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) &= \tan^2(1) + \sum_{n=2}^{N} \tan^2\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \\
&= \tan^2(1) + \sum_{n=2}^{N} \tan^2\left(\frac{x_n}{2}\right) \\
&\leq \tan^2(1) + \sum_{n=2}^{N} \left(\frac{2x_n}{\pi}\right)^2 \\
&\leq \tan^2(1) + \left(\frac{4}{\pi}\right)^2\sum_{n=2}^{N}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 \\
&\leq \tan^2(1) + \left(\frac{4}{\pi}\right)^2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2.
\end{align}
$$
It is also [well know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem) that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$, therefore, for any $N\geq 2$, we have that

$$
\begin{align}
0 \leq s_N:=\sum_{n=1}^{N} \tan^2\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) &\leq \tan^2(1) + \frac{8}{3}.
\end{align}
$$
Hence, $s_N$ is a monotonically increasing sequence which is bounded above. Therefore, it must [converge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) when $N\to\infty$, which is precisely as was required.

Answer (score 0):

Such kind of tasks you may perform (yourself) using [this WolframAlpha request](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B1%2FTan%5E2%5B%28Pi%2F2+-+1%2Fn%29%5D%2C+%7Bn%2C+1%2C+Infinity%7D%5D) inputting:

```
Sum[1/Tan^2[(Pi/2 - 1/n)], {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

As a result we obtain that your sum converges:

[image]

Comment: I believe the OP meant to say $\tan^2(x)$ with the square over $\tan$ and not the argument, in which case the sum does converge.

Comment: ok i will check this as well

Answer (score 0):

You might note that $\tan(\pi/2 - x) = \cot(x)$.  So your sum is really

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \tan^2\frac{1}{n}.$$

This should be easier to bound since $\tan x \sim x$ close to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $:$ Note that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac {\tan^2 \frac {1} {n}} {\frac {1} {n^2}} = 1 \neq 0$ and now invoke limit form of the comparison test to conclude.